# what's the difference of 'majority committed data' and 'the snapshot of majority committed data'

Tags: mongodb, transactions

What's the difference between *majority committed data* and *snapshot of majority committed data* and should I care about it? If the two concepts are totally different, when and how to choose one over the other?

I found these descriptions while I was reading the reference about transactions in mongodb: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transaction-options-read-concern-write-concern-read-preference, but I cannot understand the difference between `readConcern: majority` and `readConcern: snapshot`.

Comment: if you figured this out, I'd like to know this as well.

Comment: a clue : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation
i think , this is a clone of last majority committed when my transaction started and my transaction with `snapshot` concern worked on this clone.

Comment: @C.O. I probably found the answer

Comment: @ThinkBig I am not really sure I have understood your comment, but I think it is different from what I have found

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the documentation really takes these concepts for granted, but the difference is not that easy to understand. I am not even sure I got it right, but Aly Cabral made this example in [her talk about distributed transactions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlNDSo5XDPQ&t=340s).

If I specify `readConcern: snapshot`, then I am going to have a consistent point in time across all of the shards.

[image]

Instead if I specify `readConcern: local` or `readConcern: majority`, then I am going to have consistent snapshots per partition.

[image]

And she concludes by saying that with `readConcern: snapshot`, coordinating the snapshot finding across the sharded cluster could be expensive, so you should weigh the pros and cons of each `readConcern`.

---

She made a good example and those images really helped me, but I think an addition is necessary:

- the `time` field shown refers to the `ClusterTime`<sup>1</sup>: this is a cluster-wide logical clock based on the Hybrid Logical Clock. The primary of each shard has its own `ClusterTime` value and adheres to the following rules:

  > **ClusterTime Increment rule**:
  > The ClusterTime is incremented (“ticks”) only when there is
  > a write to a primary node’s replication operation log
  > (oplog).
  > **ClusterTime Distribution rule**:
  > Cluster nodes (mongod, mongos, config server, clients)
  > always track and include the greatest known ClusterTime
  > when sending a message.

  If in the second picture the `ClusterTime` of the transaction is chosen to be 102, the shard having `ClusterTime` 110 could have majority-committed changes that I would not want to see during the transaction. From MongoDB 5.0, this time is configurable:

  ```
  readConcern: {
      level: "snapshot",
      atClusterTime: Timestamp(1613577600, 1)
  }
  ```

I am writing a [report](https://github.com/marco-luzzara/mongodb-transaction-simulation/tree/main/doc) on MongoDB transactions where I have explained these concepts and many others. If you find errors/things to improve, I would really appreciate anyone's help.

---

<sup>1: https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/3299869.3314049</sup>